# Object as array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to group all objects of a certain type.
For example I have a class:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        //...
    }
}
```

and in the main method:

```
class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();
        A a3 = new A();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to act with objects A as if it were an array, without that I create it?
It can be as stupid question, but I wanted to remove my doubts.

Comment: No, you'll have to create the array yourself. (You may want to look into enums)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have more objects of the same type which must do all of the same methods (es. a1, a2 and a3 must all run the update() method), then it would be easier if you saw them as an array

Comment: You simply make everything recursive, and chain the objects together.  (Not really, just kidding.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are asking correctly....Creating a bunch of objects does not mean you can instantly reference them as an array. The easiest way to do something like what you might want is:

```
    ArrayList<ObjectA> list = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
       list.add(new ObjectA());
    }
```

Comment: was about to post the same thing +1

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options.  If you really want just a static initialization of an array of A values, you can do this:

```
A[] arrayOfAs = {new A(), new A(), new A()};
```

But perhaps better is this:

```
List<A> listOfAs = new ArrayList<>();
listOfAs.add(new A());
listOfAs.add(new A());
// ...
listOfAs.add(new A());
// then finally:
A[] arrayOfAs = listOfAs.toArray(new A[0]);
```

Which is better will depend on your context.  The "new A[0]" may look funny, but it is required in order to tell Java the correct type to return.

Having said that, a container class like a List may be preferable.